# .htaccess i want rewrite letters - numbers in letters/numbers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

`http:/example.com/word-123` --> `http://example.com/word/123`

i'm trying to do in this way but nothing happen

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$ [P]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule  http://prink-it.adit.it/([a-z]+)-([0-9]+) [P]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /([a-z]+)\-(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(\d+)$ /$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: @GiuseppeZagaria Your question was poorly worded... :|

Answer (score 0):

I Solved in this way

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /([a-z]+)\/(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,P]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-(\d+)$ /$1/$2 [P]
```